# DateFormat month pattern is formatted wrong

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having a pattern that should render the complete month, however, it does this strange thing where March gets formatted as M03 and it totally ignores and keeps the first M in the pattern.

[example of bad month formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHDep.png)

It's a custom view that I pass the pattern via xml.

```xml
<com.example.app.Clockview
...
app:format12Hour="EEEE MMMM dd"
app:format24Hour="EEEE MMMM dd"
...
 />
```

And I pretty much get this pattern from attributes and pass it into `Dateforma.format`

```kotlin
class ClockView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) :
    androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView(context, attrs) {
    private val typedArray =
        context.theme?.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ClockView, 0, 0)
    var format24: String? = typedArray?.getString(R.styleable.ClockView_format24Hour)
    var format12: String? = typedArray?.getString(R.styleable.ClockView_format12Hour)

    init {
        typedArray?.recycle()

        updateTime()
    }

    fun updateTime() {
            text = DateFormat.format(
                if (is24HourFormat(context)) {
                    format24
                } else {
                    format12
                }, System.currentTimeMillis()
            )

    }
...
}
```

I thought it was a bug in debug mode because I was testing some formats. However, on uninstalling from the emulator and running again it still shows like that.

Comment: I have just tested your code and my date formats perfectly fine. Have you checked that `format24` and `format12` are as you expect in `updateTime()`?

Comment: What locale/language is your device set to? Perhaps changing that will fix your problem.

Comment: Using e.g. `Locale.ROOT` would explain this

Comment: Thank you very much, I was probably using `Locale.ROOT`. We have a requirement for a menu to change language, to implement that we used a context wrapper and there was a place where I created a locale from a bogus language value.